# Make two columns on one column(python)

Tags: python, date, replace, split

`date = '2021.02.01.2021.02.07.'`
I want to divide the date into startdate and enddate like this:
`startdate = 2021.02.01` `enddate = 2021.02.07`
How to do it??(python)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the date is a string in your question you just need to split the string

```
date = '2021.02.01.2021.02.07.'
startdate = date[:10]
enddate = date[10:-1]
```

A fancier solution is to split the string with `date.split('.')` and get each field, and then built start and end dates